Is multi-threading in C++ safe? Will assertions fail?
Case
Case1:
According to the gcc documentation the following assertion will not fail
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync
-Thread 1-
x.store (1, memory_order_relaxed)
x.store (2, memory_order_relaxed)

-Thread 2-
y = x.load (memory_order_relaxed)
z = x.load (memory_order_relaxed)
assert (y <= z)

The assert cannot fail. Once the store of 2 is seen by thread 2, it can no longer see the value 1. This prevents coalescing relaxed loads of one variable across relaxed loads of a different reference that might alias. There is also the presumption that relaxed stores from one thread are seen by relaxed loads in another thread within a reasonable amount of time. That means that on non-cache-coherent architectures, relaxed operations need to flush the cache (although these flushes can be merged across several relaxed operations) The relaxed mode is most commonly used when the programmer simply wants an variable to be atomic in nature rather than using it to synchronize threads for other shared memory data.
Case2:
In the same way, case2 assertion will not fail, right?
std::atomic<bool> x{false}, y{false};

void thread1() {
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed); // (1)
    y.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed); // (2)
}

void thread2() {
    while (!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)); // (3)
    assert(x.load()); // (4)
}

test
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

std::atomic<bool> x{false}, y{false};

void thread1() {
        x.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed); // (1)
    y.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed); // (2)
}

void thread2() {
        while (!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)); // (3)
        assert(x.load()); // (4)
}

void fn() {
        int i;
        while(i < 10000000) {
                x.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                y.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
                std::thread t1(thread1);
                std::thread t2(thread2);

                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                i++;
        }
}

int main() {

        fn();
        return 0;
}


So memory_order_relaxed is safety?

Why should case 2 work, too? Is it because you don't use relaxed mem order on the second load? Apart from that, it uses two different objects, I could imagine that the stores are reordered.

Just curious - if relaxed always works, why does the standard bother with the other memory orders?

The answer to both headline questions is: It depends.

"In the same way" it's not the same. The first has one variable and the second has two. And if that surprises you, there's plenty more of even nastier surprises with atomics. You really really need to have a thorough understanding of atomics to write anything with it. Don't guess your way through and ask questions to verify your guess in an ad hoc manner.

atomic guarantees only synchronization on this variable. Two atomics do not have to be updated in order. Atomic do not provide memory barrier. If you like to have experiment which wil be able to repro issue, you need put something between x and y so they do not share chunk of memory which CPU uses as one to synchronize atomics.

Regarding the very first example you provided (not the code), you didn't define the initial value of x, so it depends on what x.load returns before x.store executes.  I mean, if x is initially 3, then the assertion can fail (as described).

Remember that some CPU architectures (like X86) make some operations safe beyond what the C++ standard guarantees, while others (like Alpha and Arm for example) most definitely do not. So your experience may very well vary depending on what CPU architecture you run your code on. To stay safe; stick to what the C++ standard guarantees. Also, you need to consider undefined behavior and what an optimizing compiler might do if you stray into that territory.

std::memory_order_relaxed is not as safe as you think. There are two things at play here that lead to the first snippet you've provided being safe, but this not being generally representative of std::memory_order_relaxed's behavior.

All threads view changes to objects in the same order. From cppreference:


They [std::memory_order_relaxed reads/writes] only guarantee atomicity and modification order consistency.


Modifications to variables in a given thread, including std::memory_order_relaxed modifications, will be perceived to happen in their stated order.

What does 2 mean? If I make two writes (i.e. write 3 to a variable and write 4 to a variable), the behavior of my program will be equivalent a state in which I first wrote 3 to a variable, and then 4. Notably, this does not require that the writes actually occur in this order, just that my behavior follows this. Notably, if there is some sort of compiler optimization that could be done by re-ordering writes / reads while preserving the local behavior, this might be done.
And so in the first example that you've constructed, the problem is that it is too simple. The behavior is too minimal for there to be some optimization that changes the order of the reads and writes. If I were to re-order the writes the behavior would change (the final value of my variable would be different). And so property 2 imposes that the writer thread will view the writes in the order that they happen, which means that property 1 imposes that the other threads will view it this way.
Note that in the second example, because we don't read either of the values x or y, it would be possible for the compiler to re-order these writes, and so your second snippet could lead to the assertion failing.
In general, in more complicated programs, the use of std::memory_order_relaxed instead of std::memory_order_release / std::memory_order_acquire allows the compiler to optimize the order of reads and writes that can lead to unexpected behavior from other threads (because property 2 says nothing about making sure execution for other threads observing the variable is respected).
So when do you want to use std::memory_order_relaxed? The classic example would be a shared atomic variable where you don't care about the order of operations, just that they are atomic - perhaps a counter where I don't care if I get 2 or 3, I just care that whatever value I get is unique. In std::shared_ptr<T>, the shared reference counter is most certainly using std::memory_order_relaxed to manage reference count. Another great use case would be some atomic variable x that has exactly one writer but many readers. The one writer thread could happily use std::memory_order_relaxed for their accesses of this variable, because from property 2, the behavior will be as expected.

No.
In case 2, we are free to reorder (2) before (1).

Case1 and Case2 are not analogous.  There is a fundamental difference in the ordering rules for two operations in the same thread on the same atomic object (as in Case1), versus on different objects (as in Case2).   Indeed, the assert in Case1 cannot fail, but in Case2 it can.

A general rule of thumb is that two operations on the same atomic object, in the same thread, will not be reordered with each other, even if they are memory_order_relaxed. They will be visible to all other threads in that same order. The formal C++ memory model guarantees this via the concept that each atomic object has its own modification order: a total order on all writes to it, which is observed by all threads and is consistent with the happens-before partial order, so that in particular it is consistent with every thread's program order.
In the C++20 standard, the modification order is defined in 6.9.2.1p4, and we can use it in conjunction with the other memory model rules to prove that the assertion in Case1 must succeed.  The store of 1 to x in thread 1 (call it S1) is sequenced-before the store of 2 (call it S2), so S1 happens-before S2 (6.9.2.1p10).  By the write-write coherence rule of 6.9.2.1p15, this means that 1 precedes 2 in the modification order of x (and the initial value of x, presumably 0, precedes them both).  Similarly, in thread 2, the load of x into y (call it L1) is sequenced-before, and therefore also happens-before, the load into z (call it L2).  By read-read coherence (6.9.2.1p16), L2 must return either the same value as L1, or a value that appears later in the modification order.  It follows that L2 cannot return a value numerically less than that returned by L1.
However, for operations on two different objects, there is no such guarantee.  It is entirely possible for them to be reordered, and for another thread to observe those two operations "out of order", unless there is an explicit memory ordering parameter or fence which blocks it.  There are no rules in the formal memory model that would allow you to prove that the assertion in Case2 must succeed.

To understand why there is a difference, let's recall that the fundamental reason to allow memory reordering is efficiency.  Think about thread 1 in Case2, and suppose that x is not present in L1 cache.  On an old-fashioned CPU, the store to x will simply stall the CPU until its cache line is loaded and the store is complete, and only then will it proceed to the next instruction and the store to y.  This could waste tens or hundreds of clock cycles.  So on a weakly ordered CPU, we allow the store to y to proceed, while still waiting on the cache line for x.  If it happens that y is already present in L1 cache, then the store to y may actually complete, and be visible to other cores, long before the store to x.  Similar reasoning shows why it could also be desirable to reorder the two loads in thread 2.
Contrast this with the situation for Case1.  If we are making two stores to the same object x, then they must both wait until the cache line for x can be loaded.  And once this happens, there isn't any performance benefit to be gained by reordering them to store 2 before 1, and allowing this would make it harder to ensure that a subsequent load within thread 1 would always return 2, as it must.  (A cardinal rule of multithreading is that all reordering within a single thread must be transparent to the thread itself, as if it were running on a simple in-order CPU.)  So it is very reasonable to require that the two stores must simply occur, and become visible, in program order.  The modification order guarantee for individual objects can be provided at no real cost to efficiency.

Your test program for Case2, as it stands, isn't going to be effective at showing the possibility of memory reordering, for several reasons.

Your variables x and y are most likely going to be allocated at adjacent addresses, within the same cache line.  This more or less makes them share a single modification order, so you won't see them reordered.  To avoid this, you can use alignas to give each one a sufficiently large alignment so that they cannot share a cache line.

You start and join a new pair of threads each time you do a test.  Given the amount of work involved in starting a thread, it's improbable that the functions thread1 and thread2 will actually end up being executed sufficiently close to each other in real time, which you need in order for the loads in thread2 to observe one of the stores in thread1 but not the other.  Instead, set up a test where you start the threads once, and let them race each other for many iterations.  See my example below.

You didn't mention where you ran your test, but it'll need to be on an architecture that actually is weakly ordered.  x86 will not work because it automatically upgrades all load instructions to acquire, and all store instructions to release.  So on x86, you would only see reordering if the compiler chose to emit the store or load instructions out of order, which although it's permitted, is unlikely, as there is no particular benefit to doing so.


Try the following instead.  The assertion fails quickly on a 4-core ARM64 Linux computer (Raspberry Pi 5).
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

alignas(64) std::atomic<unsigned long> x{0}, y{0};

void thread1() {
    unsigned long i = 0;
    while (true) {
        x.store(i, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        y.store(i, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        i++;
    }
}

void thread2() {
    while (true) {
        unsigned long xx, yy;
        yy = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        xx = x.load();
        assert(xx >= yy);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(thread1);
    std::thread t2(thread2);
    t1.join(); // never happens
    t2.join();
}


